# How to use a dynamic length for a built-in function

Tags: pine-script

I want to use a dynamic length for a built-in function, like `sma`. As I understand pine script is executed for each historical bar from the beginning. I want it to calculate `sma(1)` for first bar, `sma(2)` for second bar and `sma(bar_index)` for the most recent bar. How do I accomplish that? `bar_index` is not accepted since it is not an integer. How do I get a number of current bar as an integer, not series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to compute is called a cumulative mean, and can easily be done in Pinescript as follows:

```
cum(close)/bar_index
```

Answer (score 1):

It's nice to see authors paying attention to the handling of the oft-overlooked first bars.

See `Sma()` by alexgrover in our [Functions Allowing Series As Length - PineCoders FAQ](https://www.tradingview.com/script/kY5hhjA7-Functions-Allowing-Series-As-Length-PineCoders-FAQ/).

Comment: Can you please show me how to make a call to `Sma(src,p) => a = cum(src), (a - a[max(p,0)])/max(p,0)` so that SMA length would increase with each new bar? Is it `Sma(close, bar_index)`?